# How to create our own method just like polling in selenium does?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I want to create a method which will acts like fluentWeight method in Selenium. This method should check particular element present on page or not periodically. It should work for each and every element on page.

Comment: Which language are you coding in?

Comment: Sounds very good. Have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can do it.  One way to do it is to create your own method that takes a "By" locator as an argument and use a JavascriptExecutor within the method to do your stuff.  Personally, I don't see a reason not to use Selenium built-in methods along with ExpectedConditions class.